App themes are not automatically applied when changing GTK or QT themes
Problematic
I'm working with xmonad WM and I want to add a keybinding to switching themes. I already did that and it seems to work.
The issue is that apps such as Brave or Firefox do not update their theme on the run, and I have to close and open the apps again in order for the theme to be applied.
Does anybody know what is going on?
My configuration
I opted to switch themes by overwritting the theme directly on the GTK and QT configuration files ($HOME/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini and $HOME/.config/qt5ct/qt5ct.conf, respectively) via sed. I have keybound the commands in xmonad's config file.
What I have tried

Setting the theme via: gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme "<theme-name>".
Sending signals such as HUP or USR1 to the apps: pkill -HUP -x brave


I have solved it by installing the xsettingsd package (sudo apt install xsettingsd) and placing in the xmonad.hs config file a function that changes the theme via sed. The whole function I used is the following one:
toggleTheme :: X ()
toggleTheme = do
  let themeFile = "/tmp/current_theme"  -- Temporary file to track the theme
  fileExists <- io $ doesFileExist themeFile
  if fileExists
      then do
          -- If the file exists, switch to the dark theme and delete the file
          spawn "sed -i 's#color_scheme_path=/usr/share/qt5ct/colors/airy.conf#color_scheme_path=/usr/share/qt5ct/colors/darker.conf#' ~/.config/qt5ct/qt5ct.conf"
          spawn "sed -i 's/gtk-theme-name=Yaru/gtk-theme-name=Yaru-dark/' ~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini"
          spawn "sed -i 's#Net/ThemeName \"Yaru\"#Net/ThemeName \"Yaru-dark\"#' ~/.config/xsettingsd/xsettingsd.conf"
          spawn "killall -HUP xsettingsd"
          io $ removeFile themeFile  -- Create the file to indicate dark theme
      else do
          -- If the file does not exist, switch to the light theme and create the file
          spawn "sed -i 's#color_scheme_path=/usr/share/qt5ct/colors/darker.conf#color_scheme_path=/usr/share/qt5ct/colors/airy.conf#' ~/.config/qt5ct/qt5ct.conf"
          spawn "sed -i 's/gtk-theme-name=Yaru-dark/gtk-theme-name=Yaru/' ~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini"
          spawn "sed -i 's#Net/ThemeName \"Yaru-dark\"#Net/ThemeName \"Yaru\"#' ~/.config/xsettingsd/xsettingsd.conf"
          spawn "killall -HUP xsettingsd"
          io $ writeFile themeFile ""  -- Create the file to indicate light theme

Notice that I left the previous sed commands just in case, and that after overwriting xsettingsd's config file I have make xsettingsd it reload it again with the killall -HUP xsettingsd command.
In the same xmonad.hs file bind the function to a key and it works.
((modm, xK_s), toggleTheme)

